# Bijection between $2^{\Sigma^*}$ and $\mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, regular-language, turing-machines, decidability

Is there a Bijection in  between $2^{\Sigma^*}$ and $\mathbb R$? Here $2^{\Sigma^*}$ denotes the set of all languages over a finite alphabet.

If I have an uncountable set, then its powerset will also be uncountable, but there is no bijection between them.

Of course, sometimes I can find a bijection between two uncountable set: take any uncountable set and itself. And, there is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R. $ 
But my question is there is there any possibility of bijection between two uncountable set $2^{\Sigma^*}$ and $\mathbb R$ where $2^{\Sigma^*}$ is the set of all languages. I know that the set $2^{\Sigma^*} $ is uncountable by cantors theorem.

Comment: Well, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719885/bijection-between-0-1-and-the-space-of-binary-sequences) shows that $2^{\mathbb N}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$. So all you need to show is that $\Sigma^*$ is countable.

Comment: $\Sigma^*$ is easy to proof countable but there is possible one-to-one correspondence possible between $2^{\Sigma^*}$ and $\mathbb R$?

Comment: There's a one to one correspondence between $2^{\mathbb N}$ and $\mathbb R$, so yes.

Comment: But what about $2^{\Sigma^*}$ and $\mathbb R$?

Comment: $\Sigma^*$ is countable, so $2^{\mathbb N}$ is in a one to one correspondence with $2^{\Sigma^*}$...

Comment: @Don if your comments insert into answer I will accept it.

Comment: It depends on your vocabulary is it countable?

Comment: @Math how is it countable?

Comment: @User4567 I mean the alphabet your working on? what is it?

Comment: is it {0,1}? something else?

Comment: @Math you are saying alphabet about of $2^{\Sigma^*}$?

Comment: @Math {0,1} or {a, b} whatever.

Comment: @User4567 ok consider my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you are working over the  alphabet, $A=\{ 0,1 \},$ the set of all finite strings over $A$ obviously has cardinality of the naturals, now in order to get the cardinality of all languages over $A$ you want the cardinality of the  power set of the set of all strings  which is the cardinality of the the power set of the naturals. It is a well known theorem that the power set of the naturals is equinumoruous with $\mathbb{R}$ whose proof can found in text on real analysis. Note that you can replace $A$ with any finite set.